# ActiveMQ binary distribution via Maven

Tags: maven, activemq-classic

I am looking for the full binary distribution of ActiveMQ in the Maven repositories but can't find it. Only the [SNAPSHOT repository](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/activemq/apache-activemq/) contains full distributions.

Does anyone know why or where I can get it from?

Comment: [ActiveMQ website](http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-5100-release.html)?

Comment: Would [mvnrepository's entry for activemq-all](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-all) do the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its easy to find, its here

```
org.apache.activemq/apache-activemq
```

And there is a .zip or .tar.gz download you can find at,

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.activemq%7Capache-activemq%7C5.10.0%7Cpom